# Azure Kubernetes - Internal LoadBalancer with Https Service?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-load-balancer

I have deployed my kubernetes application on AKS, it uses the Internal Loadbalancer without a separate Ingress Controller.

Currently the service is accessible using http protocol and I want to secure the service. How do I enable https and where should I install the certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal loadbalancer is a layer 4 service, you will need a layer 7 ingress controller like [Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview) or roll your own ingress controller for SSL.

see:
[Configuring an AKS load balancer for HTTPS access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383614/configuring-an-aks-load-balancer-for-https-access)